# How to display self pointing table?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, mariadb

I've a table named category. Some categories are sub-categories of other categories.

```
--------------------------
ID | Name | Upper_Category
--------------------------
```

`Upper_Category` references to another category's `ID`.
I need to display the table like so:

```
ID | Name    | Upper_Category
1  | ROOT #1 | NULL
5  | exam #2 | 1
7  | exam #3 | 1
4  | ROOT #2 | NULL
9  | exam #4 | 4
2  | exam #5 | 4
3  | exam #6 | 4
6  | ROOT #3 | NULL
...
```

The categories whichs `Upper_Category` is `NULL` display first and then the sub-categories which reference to them.

I tried a lot by USING JOINS and UNION but didnt succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `case` in `order by` clause:

```
select *
from table1
order by case when Upper_Category is null then id else upper_category end, upper_category
```

**Result:**

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| ID |  Name   | Upper_Category |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 | ROOT #1 | NULL           |
|  5 | exam #2 | 1              |
|  7 | exam #3 | 1              |
|  4 | ROOT #2 | NULL           |
|  9 | exam #4 | 4              |
|  2 | exam #5 | 4              |
|  3 | exam #6 | 4              |
|  6 | ROOT #3 | NULL           |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZWD85522)**

Comment: Thank you that is excatly I was looking for +1

Answer (score 0):

If there can be more than one level of categories a [recursive Common Table Expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) can be used:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE upper_category IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT t1.* FROM t1, r1 WHERE r1.id = t1.upper_category)
SELECT * FROM r1;

+------+---------+----------------+
| id   | data    | upper_category |
+------+---------+----------------+
|    1 | ROOT #1 |           NULL |
|    4 | ROOT #2 |           NULL |
|    6 | ROOT #3 |           NULL |
|    5 | exam #2 |              1 |
|    7 | exam #3 |              1 |
|    9 | exam #4 |              4 |
|    2 | exam #5 |              4 |
|    3 | exam #6 |              4 |
+------+---------+----------------+
```